# AS3 goto next frame with hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm making a game in which you have to pick up a key first with your character and then go to the door. When you hit the door, you should go to the next frame. Without the key, you can't pass the door. You should pick up the key with hitTestObject and go to the next frame with hitTestObject too.

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Here is my code:

var gotKey:Boolean = false;

```
if(Jack.hitTestObject (unlock))
{
    unlock.visible = false;
    gotKey == true;
    trace ("You got the key!")
}
if (Jack.hitTestObject (house))
{
    if (gotKey == true)
    nextFrame();
    trace ("level achieved")
}
```

Comment: ummm... so what's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting a compile error, or are you looking for help with the logic? Because what you've got should work, but you've left out a set of curly braces on the gotKey logic check where Jack hitTestObjects house.

```
if (Jack.hitTestObject (house))
{
    if (gotKey == true)
    nextFrame();
    trace ("level achieved")
}
```

should be

```
if (Jack.hitTestObject (house))
{
    if (gotKey == true) {
    nextFrame();
    trace ("level achieved")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to assign the variable gotKey to true (=), instead of comparing it to true (==)

```
if(Jack.hitTestObject (unlock))
{
    unlock.visible = false;
    gotKey == true;
    trace ("You got the key!")
}
```

should be:

```
if(Jack.hitTestObject (unlock))
{
    unlock.visible = false;
    gotKey = true;
    trace ("You got the key!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpfull! But an error pops up: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. And antoher question: You could go to the house now, before getting the key first. How could I solve that?